# Emberjs: best way to iterate through ArrayProxy content?

Tags: ember.js

Often, I need to loop through an Ember.ArrayProxy object's content.

**Exemple 1**, I need to build a list of IDs:

```
var loc = myArrayProxy.get('length') || 0,
    ids = new Array(),
    idsList;

while(--loc >= 0) {
    var curObject = myArrayProxy.objectAt(loc);
    ids.push(curObject.id);
}
idsList = ids.join(',');
```

**Exemple 2**, I need to build an Array of primitive objects (not Ember.Object):

```
var loc = myArrayProxy.get('length') || 0,
    newContent = new Array();

while(--loc >= 0) {
    var curObject = myArrayProxy.objectAt(loc);
    newContent.push({
                      id:   curObject.id,
                      name: curObject.name
                   });
}
```

**Question: is there a better way to do this? The "while(--loc >= 0)" seems bad to me.**

Comment: Now using "getEach()" and "forEach()". The documentation really lacks examples... Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ember.ArrayProxy provides many friendly functions (through Ember.Array, Ember.Enumerable, ...). Loops can often be avoided using "forEach". In your 2nd example, you may consider using "map".
Here is a link to [Ember.ArrayProxy documentation](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.ArrayProxy&src=false).
Be sure to look at: [Ember.Array](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Array&src=false) and [Ember.Enumerable](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Enumerable&src=false)

edit:

For instance, assuming the order of the ids is not relevant, your first example could be written:

```
var idsList = myArrayProxy.mapProperty('id').join(',');
```